# Filter columns with multiple criteria VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to filter and update data, but I realized that my code is not filtering correctly.

I need to Filter Column "Material Type" = "ZSFG", "Material Description" = "<>*SYRUP" (anything that does not contain the word syrup), and Planned Deliv. Time"= "<>0" OR "<>" (anything but zero or empty). then clear all other values.

I am using the following code, but I am not sure what I am missing:

```
Sub Delivery_Time()


Dim rg As Range
Dim Filter1, Filter6, Filter As Variant

Worksheets("MARC").Activate

Set rg = Worksheets("MARC").Range("A1").CurrentRegion


Filter1 = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="MATERIAL TYPE", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Filter6 = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Planned Deliv. Time", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Filter = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="MATERIAL DESCRIPTION", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

On Error Resume Next

With rg
   .AutoFilter Field:=Filter1, Criteria1:="ZSFG", Operator:=xlFilterValues
   .AutoFilter Field:=Filter, Criteria1:="*SYRUP*"
   .AutoFilter Field:=Filter6, Criteria2:="<>0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria1:="<>"


    With .Columns(Filter6).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
       With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
          .Clear
            With .Interior
              .Pattern = xlSolid
              .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
              .Color = 65535
              .TintAndShade = 0
              .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
      End With
   End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Criteria1:="*SYRUP*"` doesn't match your description. When in doubt, you can apply the filters manually while recording a macro, and then inspect the recorded code.

Comment: it does fin the "Material Description" column with the cells containing SYRUP. However, the Planned Deliv. Time shows everything that has zero or it's empty. I need to also filter this column to anything BESIDES zero or blank

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the filter criteria name should be the same:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=Filter6, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria1:="<>"
```

Comment: You might as well just remove the `, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria1:="<>"`. This is the result of that line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpNK2.png